# Google Maps Javascript API loadGeoJson styling problem

Tags: google-maps, geojson

How can I download the GeoJson, but not show it on the map? I thought "visible: false" would do this, but it's still displaying the GeoJson on the map. I want it to be downloaded but not displayed, so that when the user later clicks a button, it will display immediately without the download delay (it's a large GeoJson file that takes 2-5 secs to download).

```
let map;
let datalayer1;
let infowindow;

async function initMap() {
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -37.022157, lng: 144.884673 },
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
  });

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

datalayer1 = new google.maps.Data({map:map});

  datalayer1.setStyle({
    fillColor: '#00d01b',
    strokeColor: '#00d01b',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    visibile: false
  })

datalayer1.loadGeoJson("http://myremoteurl.com/sw.json")
```

I've tried running "datalayer1.setStyle({visible: false})" from the browser console after the page has loaded, and it does indeed make the GeoJson invisible, but why is it appearing in the first place when the styles visible tag is already set to false?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the style needs to be set on every feature in the loaded GeoJson data layer.

I did it like this, just after the GeoJson is loaded.

```js
datalayer1.setStyle(function(feature){
     return {
             visible: false
    };
  });
```